# Настройка виртуальных хостов Tomcat

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, virtual-hosts

Есть имя хоста `test.mydomain.com`. Вбиваю его в адресную строку, попадаю в панель управления Tomcat.

На томкате развернуто приложение и по адресу `localhost/test/` оно запускается. Приложение развернуто в локальной папке `webapps/test`

Теперь хочу, чтобы при обращении к хосту `test.mydomain.com` перебрасывало на мое приложение. Добавляю в server.xml в секцию `<Engine>`

```xml
  <Host name="test.mydomain.com"  appBase="webapps/test"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>www.test.mydomain.com</Alias>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="test_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
```

И получаю в браузере

> **Message** Not found
>   **Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

А в логе `test_access_log` надпись

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [20/Sep/2019:16:07:39 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1077
```

Tomcat 9.0.7

Что я делаю не так?

**Update**

А обращение к `www.test.mydomain.com` выбрасывает по прежнему на главную страницу томката

**Update2**

Добавил в `<Host>` параметр

```
<Context path="" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/test"
   debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
```

все почти заработало. Кроме одного момента.

Вот мой web.xml

```xml
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">
  <display-name>Test Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

И определены у меня два таких сервлета

```
@WebServlet(name = "Options", urlPatterns = "/js/options.js")
public class Options extends HttpServlet {

@WebServlet(name = "AggregateIconController", urlPatterns = "/images/points/agg.svg")
public class AggregateIconController extends HttpServlet {
```

т.е. connection point является подмножеством масок, определенных в web.xml.

При обращении к адресу `test.mydomain.com/js/options.js` получаю ошибку 404. При обращении к `localhost/test/js/options.js` страница возвращается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все у меня заработало. Что сделал

1. Вынес приложения для этого хоста в отдельную папку, лежащую вне `${catalina.base}/webapps` об этом говорится в [документации](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/TomcatDevelopmentVirtualHosts) к томкату

   > In order to create virtual hosts, do the following:
   >
   > 1. Create a separate directory for each host **outside of $CATALINA_HOME/webapps**
   > 2. Underneath each directory, create a webapps directory.
2. В `server.xml` оставил только строчки

   ```xml
   <Host name="test.mydomain.com"  appBase="test/webapps"
           unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
     <Alias>www.test.mydomain.com</Alias>
     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
            prefix="test_access_log" suffix=".txt"
            pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
   </Host>
   ```
3. Исходный war переименовал в `ROOT.war` и положил в папку `test/webapps`. Tomcat его сам задеплоил в `test/webapps/ROOT`
4. По поводу сервлетов так и не понял. Для

   ```java
   @WebServlet(name = "Options", urlPatterns = "/js/options.js")
   public class Options extends HttpServlet {
   ```

   явно прописал в `web.xml`

   ```xml
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Options</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/js/options.js</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

   (до этого такой подход все равно не работал).

   А для

   ```java
   @WebServlet(name = "AggregateIconController", urlPatterns = "/images/points/agg.svg")
   public class AggregateIconController extends HttpServlet {
   ```

   все заработало само